# Why the custom rule is not working? (allow user to select only the quantity for one registration type)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select menu for the user to select the quantities of each 
registration type that he wants.

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('conferences.storeQuantities', 
['id' => $conference->id, 'slug' => $conference->slug])}}">
    <ul class="list-group">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
        <li>
            <select id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}" 
                    data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}"
                    name="rtypes[{{ $rtype->name }}]">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype-> max_participants; $i++)
                    <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                @endfor
            </select>
        </li>
       @endforeach
    </ul>
</form>
```

But there are some validation rules for this field that are not working properly. Basically there are 4 things that should be validated:

- the field is required
- the quantity introduced by the user should be between min_participants and max_participants (min_participants and max_participants are columns in the registration_types table and means the minimum and maximum quantity that a user can select for a specific registration)
- the user needs to at least select the quantity for a registration type available for the confernece and for the other registration types should be allowed to select "0"
- but the user can´t introduce the quantity "0" for all registration types available in the conference

**Issue:** But its not working properly, if the user selects for example the quantity "1" for registration type "general" and for the registration type "plus" "0" it appears the validation error defined in the `message()` of the `RegistrationTypeQuantity` rule. But the user should be able to select only the quantity for 1 registration type.

Do you know how to solve that?

The `RegistrationTypeQuantity` rule that is used in the storeQuantities(), basically the quantities are sum and then is checked if the quantity is greater than 0:

```
 public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {

        $quantity = 0;

        foreach($value as $key=>$v) {

            if ( is_null($v)) return false;

            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->first();
            if ( ! $rtype) return false;

            // $rtype was found
            if ( ($v < $rtype->min_participants || $v > $rtype->max_participants) )
                return false;
        }

        // track total quantity selected
        $quantity += (int)$v;

        // make sure there was at least one purchase
        if ($quantity === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Method to store the selected quantities by the user for each registration type

```
 public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
 {
     $request->validate([
        'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
    ]);
        if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'quantitiesError');
    }

    $rtypeQuantities = $request->get('rtypes');
    $total = 0;
    $selectedRtypes = [];


    foreach ($rtypeQuantities as $rtypeName => $quantity) {
        if ($quantity) {
            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name', $rtypeName)->firstOrFail();

            //dd($rtype);
            $price = $rtype->price;

            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
            $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;

            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions'] = $rtype->questions;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['id'] = $rtype->id;
        }
    }
    if($selectedRtypes){
        Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
        Session::put('customQuestions', $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);
        Session::put('total', $total);
    }
    return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
     }
 }
```

HTML of the select menu to select the quantities:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span>Registration Type</span>
    <span>Quantity</span>
    <span>Price</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card_body">
    <form method="post"
          action="https://proj.test/conference/1/conference-test/registration">

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <div class="w-100 text-truncate">
            <span>general</span>
          </div>
          <select class="custom-select form-control rtype_name" id="rtype_1"
                  data-price="5"
                  name="rtypes[geral]">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
          </select>
          <span>X 5.00€</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <div class="w-100 text-truncate">
            <span>plus</span>
          </div>
          <select class="custom-select form-control rtype_name" id="rtype_3"
                  data-price="10"
                  name="rtypes[plus]">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
          </select>
          <span>X 10.00€</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Validation rules better explained:

If there are two registration types associated with the conference (general and plus), the registration type "general" has the column "min_participants" as "1" and max_participants as "1", the the registration type "plus" has the column "min_participants" as "1" and max_participants as "2".

- If the user click "Next" in the select menu with quantity "0" for registration type "general" and quantity "0" for the registration type "plus" it should **fail** because the user needs to select at least the quantity for one registration type, because a registration needs to have some registration type(s) associated
- If the user click "Next" in the select menu with quantity "2" for registration type "general" and quantity "0" for the registration type "plus" it should **fail** because "general" has "max_participants" as "1" and the user selected the quantity "2" (introduced 2 in the source code for example since in the select menu 2 should not appear for the registration type general, only should appear values between 1 and 1)
- If the user click "Next" in the select menu with quantity "1" for registration type "general" and quantity "1" for the registration type "plus" it should **pass**
- If the user click "Next" in the select menu with quantity "1" for registration type "general" and quantity "0" for the registration type "plus" it should **pass** because the user should be allowed do a registration without select quantities for all registration types, because the user might want to only do a registration in the registration type "general" and none in the registration type "plus". So it should not be mandatory for the user select quantities for all registration types.

Comment: I'm not sure about your actual problem. It looks like your problem is with the registration type selects rather than the validation rule. Could you explain further? Also I think it would help out posting your rendered form with the select options.

Comment: Thanks, I upated the question with the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, so I understand there are combinations for both quantites that you want to allow and others you want to disallow. Is that correct? In that case could you display such combinations grouped on the desired correct validation result vs your current failing behavior?

Comment: The user can only select a quantity between the min_participants and max_participants. But for example if the conference has two registration types "general" and "plus". And the user want to do a registration only in the registration type "general" he should be able to select for example quantity "1" for the registration type "general" but for the registration type "plus" he should be allowed to select "0". But also for a user to do a registration needs to at least select  a quantity greater than 0 for at least one registration type.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to get the point. But I'm getting confused with your business domain logic, as most people coming to help may not be familiar with your app purpose. Could you abstract the problem to the validation itself? I think it should be easy to dump a table with the possible values and the validation results (the current *incorrect* and the expected *correct*). I mean some thing like [this example](https://pastebin.com/sYZD6CU1)

Comment: Thanks, I upated the question with more detailed info about the rules.

Comment: Thanks, looks like its now a bit clearer. So could you add the *current* behavior to each case to see *where* in contrast is the problem?

Comment: What I understand so far is the you have two selects but you need your user to pick from only one of them?

Comment: Its only 1 select menu that can have multiple registration types, the user needs to select at least the quantity for one registration type to do the registration, the registration type is like a ticket type.

Comment: Maybe the validation logic is not the problem, although there is still no proof that its correct. You havent listed your validation params. Ie rtype-&gt;min_participants and rtype-&gt;max_participants. Also, it would help for debug knowing which of the return false is being triggered. Set up a few dump or dd to trace that down and spot the condition branch that triggers your validation.

Comment: In the db both registration types of the question example (general and plus) have min_participants as "1" and max_participants as "2".

Comment: I see, so what aspect makes the difference on the validation rule executed? What is quantity related to about the form?

Comment: It seems that it enters always in this if "  if ( is_null($v)) return false;

                $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->first();

                dump('test1');".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177307/discussion-between-alariva-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [discussion that took place](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177307/discussion-between-alariva-and-john) and the analysis of the [current vs desired validation results](https://pastebin.com/6LS3a6Wr).

Follows the working code for the validation rule:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    // we get the products quantity
    $count = array_sum($value);

    // FAIL in advance if no products were selected
    if($count == 0){
      return false;
    }

    foreach($value as $key=>$v) {

        $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->first();
        if ( !$rtype ){
          return false;
        }

        // Only if at least one product was selected, test against DB params
        if ( $v != 0 && ($v < $rtype->min_participants || $v > $rtype->max_participants) ){
          return false;
        }
    }

    // If no rejectig conditions were found, validation should PASS
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at all the details but for me the problem is here:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    foreach($value as $key=>$v) {

        $quantity = 0;
```

You set quantity to 0 in each iteration. Probably you should do it like this

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $quantity = 0;

    foreach($value as $key=>$v) {
```

so you should initialized this variable with 0 before starting the loop.

Comment: Thanks but like that also dont works correct. If the user select for example "1" for the registration type "general" and "0" for the registration tpye "plus" it appears a validation error, but should not.